# Regex recursive special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been doing field validation that should allow a-z characters, spaces, hyphens and periods. The regex is:

`/^[a-zA-Z-. ]+$/`

For the most part, the following works; however, it fails if either `-` or `.` are repeated:

`String` = true,
`Str- in.g` = true,
`String--` = false,
`String...` = false

I know that in some cases, the `-` and `.` should be escaped but I don't believe they need to be in this case as they are within the [ ].

Comment: Do you want `/^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[-. ][a-zA-Z]+)*$/`?

Comment: In [character classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes) (`[...]`), the hyphen is a special character except when it is the first or the last character in the class. While as you use it could be considered non-ambiguous (you definitely do not want a range there, the last range ends on `Z`), the regex engine might have a different opinion about that. Play safe and put `-` right after `[` or just before `]`.

Answer (score 0):

It returns true for all the strings, what have you tried that's returning false for matching

```js
let reg = /^[a-zA-Z-. ]+$/

let tests = ["String", "Str- in.g", "String--", "String...", "String...---str.ing---"]

tests.forEach((item) => {
    console.log(`${item} : ${reg.test(item)}`)
})
```

Comment: The unescaped hyphen after the `Z` is in an undefined state and might produce different results based on regex implementation. Either `\-` escape it, or put it at the beginning or end of the character class.

Answer (score 0):

From docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes:

> A character class. Matches any one of the enclosed characters. You can specify a range of characters by using a hyphen, but if the hyphen appears as the first or last character enclosed in the square brackets, it is taken as a literal hyphen to be included in the character class as a normal character.

That is, if you use the hyphen not at the beginning or end, or as a range delimiter, it is in an undefined state, and depending on the regex implementation it will do one thing or another. So, unless in a range, always put the hyphen at the beginning or end, or `\-` escape it.

Fixed regex with tests:

```js
[ 'String', 'Str- in.g', 'String--', 'String...', 'Not good!' ]
.forEach(str => {
  let match = /^[a-zA-Z. -]+$/.test(str);
  console.log(str, '==>', match);
});
```

Output:

```
String ==> true
Str- in.g ==> true
String-- ==> true
String... ==> true
Not good! ==> false
```

Comment: Thanks, guys. I found the issue; it wasn't the regex itself; it was that typing `--` or `...` transformed the character from `en-dash` to `em-dash` and three `single periods` to a `horizontal ellipsis`. Source: https://www.ascii-code.com/